# How to use my own typescript definition file?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

When I run `tsc` on my project, I got an error saying that

> node_modules/@my/my-lib/src/menu/link/multiSelectList.d.ts(1,44):
>   error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module
>   'webdriverio'.
>   'D:/GIT/my-automation-tests/app1-test/node_modules/webdriverio/build/index.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.

Here is the details:

The diagram below is the original. `@my/my-lib` is my library. It will be deployed on an internal NPM registry and used by other projects.
[image]

I have to change something in `spectron` so I did it and deployed it on the internal NPM. Then I have found that the dependency `@types/webdriverio` has a lot of issues. So I fixed them and **added the definition file `webdriverio.d.ts` into `@my/my-lib`**. I tested `@my/my-lib` and it is fine.
[image]

List of changes:

1. Added `webdriverio.d.ts` to `/src/typings`
2. Changed imports to `import { SpectronClient } from '@my/spectron';`
3. Added `"typeRoots"` in tsconfig.json.

Here is the tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,     
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "typeRoots": [ 
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./src/typings"]
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "./test/**/*",
    "./index.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

Then I packed and deployed `@my/my-lib` on the internal NPM. After that, I created a new project, "app1-test", and installed `@my/my-lib`.

[image]

When I run `tsc` on this new project, I got the error above.

The point is, do I need to add `"typeRoots"` in "app1-test" like this?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
   ...
    "declaration": true,
    "typeRoots": [ 
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/@my/my-lib/src/typings"]
  },
  ...
}
```

Can anyone help me on this, please?

Comment: What you did in `@my/my-lib` to fix `webdriverio` typing, you have to do the same thing in `app1-test`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types), you can fine control how tsc discover typings for a module with multiple strategies.

Below is the solution I'd recommend for your case, all steps meant apply to `app1-test`.

1. copy the problematic `@types/webdriverio`, fix it and put it to your internal npm registry, publish it as, say `@goodtypes/webdriverio`
2. install `@goodtypes/webdriverio`, not `@types/webdriverio`
3. `tsconfig.json -> compilerOptions -> typeRoots` = `["./node_modules/@types", "./node_modules/@goodtypes"]`

If you prefer to put your good types in source code instead of publishing as npm package, just specify path to the source as item of `typeRoots`.